# store 2 websites in 1 file and dynamically change between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

so this is a very vague question but say I had a single .html file and I wanted to store essentially 2 websites in the one file and swap to the 2nd page when a condition became true on the first page(preferably a onclick javascript event) kind of like an if statement(if condition A becomes true on page one: show page 2     else: continue to show page 1) would this be possible in just javascript or would I need the aid of other programming languages and what would be the most optimum way of going about this? I would want the data entered in an input feild on page 1 also available on page 2.

sorry for vague question and horrible formatting, this is my first ever question.

Comment: it's very vague. By instinct i would tell you to study PHP with some database.

Comment: If you need to change pages on click, you only need HTML, just use two pages with an <a> element in each of them. The href would point to the other HTML file. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Joel, I don't have enough reputation to comment and so I must type an answer.

Local storage allows you to store a value (page number to display) within the user's local browser memory. This value can be tested for existence (useful for true/false conditions) and can be read (for meaningful values).

All you need to do is bind the creation of a simple local storage object (the page number to display). Bind the code to create the storage object to whichever event you want (such as a button click).

```
localStorage.setItem('entryPage', '2');
```

You will also need some code to read within the HTML file to decide what to display (via scroll, hidden and displayed DIV elements or whatever technique you are using).

```
if(localStorage.getItem('entryPage')) {
  //show page two code
}
```

Check here for a full tutorial set:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Below is a chrome-tested one-page solution just demonstrating the concept of the local storage part. You'll always be within the same HTML file, but load will show content one until you click the button and set local storage to display page 2, then any future load will be page two until you clear local storage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div id="main-container">
    <div id="content-one" style="display:block;">
    <p>This is page one content</p>
    <button id="showTwo">Show Page 2</button>
    </div>
    <div id="content-two" style="display:none">
    <p>this is content for page 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
//this function actually swaps display
function swapper(){
  document.getElementById('content-one').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('content-two').style.display = 'block';
}
//if the value exists in storage, swap them
if(localStorage.getItem('entryPage')) {
  swapper();
}
//when button clicked, swap them and store value
var btn = document.getElementById("showTwo");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){swapper();localStorage.setItem('entryPage', '2');}, false);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

To clear local storage on Chrome, see LOCAL AND SESSION section here:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/resource-panel#local-and-session-storage

And below is a version including a text-box which simply used the value of the local storage object to hold the data you wish to carry to content page 2. (Remember, if you have tested the first example above you must clear local storage to use this example below because otherwise it will never show you the first content pane).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div id="main-container">
    <div id="content-one" style="display:block;">
    <p>This is page one content</p>
    <input type="text" id="theInput"></input>
    <button id="showTwo">Show Page 2</button>
    </div>
    <div id="content-two" style="display:none">
    <p>this is content for page 2</div>
    <p id="theOutput"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
//this function actually swaps display and shows the value from page 1 textbox
function swapper(theValue){
  document.getElementById('content-one').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('content-two').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('theOutput').innerText = theValue;  
}
//if the value exists in storage, swap them and pass on the value of textbox
if(localStorage.getItem('entryPage')) {
  swapper(localStorage.getItem('entryPage'));
}

//when button clicked, swap them and store value
var btn = document.getElementById("showTwo");   
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var theData = document.getElementById("theInput").value;    
    swapper();
    localStorage.setItem('entryPage', theData);
}, false);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PS - Please note I understood the question to mean you have to contain the HTML for both pages within a single HTML file. Otherwise, just use a link and I can't believe I answered... doh!! I was only trying to help!

Comment: thank you for a detailed answer, I'm still struggling to understand the concept you're trying to show me so I don't yet understand if your solution will work for me but I will definitely do some more research and look at the tutorial you linked

Comment: @JoelEiszele I have added a working example with comments. Please paste it into an html file and open in Chrome. Local storage works in all major browsers now (see here: http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage). Please vote me up I've given you all I can here :)

Comment: @JoelEiszele I've now added a full example with a textbox too. These examples are basic but easily adaptable. For info on seeing and deleted local storage values in Chrome see LOCAL AND SESSION section here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/resource-panel. Please give me some credit I've tried hard here to turn a down-voted question into a success :)

Comment: This would have been a very large comment! +1 for full detailed answer